# How to calculate time complexity of a recursive function?

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity

What is  the time complexity of the following code?

**My guess:**

The for loop runs for constant time i.e. 3. And the function calls itself with n/3. So 'n' is contracted by 3 times every time and the time complexity is O(log<sub>3</sub>N)?

```
void function(int n){
    if(n == 1)
        return 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        cout << "Hello";
    }
    function(n/3);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's O(log<sub>3</sub>N). Call the amount of work done by the loop C. The first few calls will go:

`f(n) = C + f(n/3) = C + C + f(n/9) = C + ... + C + f(1)`

The number of times C appears will be the number of times you can divide n by 3 before it gets to 1, which is exactly log<sub>3</sub>n. So the total work is C*log<sub>3</sub>n, or O(log<sub>3</sub>N).